# How to debug OnStop in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling

I have written that is attaching the adding the new task schedular. The code able to register task scheduler on `Onstart` and the code is working perfectly and able to debug the code. But i want to do some task onStop but i am not able to debug. What is the option and what i need to do to debug the onStop code. Because when i press stop button in visual studio the program stop but not onStop code part can debug.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); 
    
                try
                {

                  // Other code where i am able to debug 
                }
                catch (Exception ie)
                {
                    StreamWriter sw;
                    sw = File.AppendText("D:\\DvrService.txt");
                    sw.WriteLine(ie.Message);
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }


        protected override void OnStop()
          {
            try
            {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();                

                foreach (string key in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
                {
                    var chromeDriverProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().Where(pr => pr.ProcessName == key.ToUpper()); // without '.exe'

                    foreach (var process in chromeDriverProcesses)
                    {
                        process.Kill();

                        StreamWriter sw;
                        sw = File.AppendText("E:\\DvrService.txt");
                        sw.WriteLine("Trying to kill Service" + key);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: Log this error
                StreamWriter sw;
                sw = File.AppendText("E:\\DvrService.txt");
                sw.WriteLine("Trying to kill Service");
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
```

Program.CS

```
static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Service1 myService = new Service1();
            myService.onDebug();
            
   
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

#else

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                    { 
                        new Service1() 
                    };
                    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

#endif

        }
```

Comment: Pressing the stop button in VS will kill the process. How are you debugging the start of a windows service? Because you haven't included any of that context in your code.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Breakpoint hit onStart in my code so i am able to debug that part

Comment: How can I tell that your `OnStart` method was called because you actually started a windows service? You haven't included anywhere near enough context to work that out.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman i have include all main codes

Comment: While you can directly extend `ServiceBase`, I wouldn't recommend it. I would separate your start / stop code into an `IHostedService` class, use the generic host (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) in your `Main()` method, which you can debug using visual studio. And call `services.AddWindowsService()` to handle start / stop events when your program is started from a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the "Stop" button in Visual Studio is not the same as stopping a Windows Service.

If you want to debug OnStop in a Windows Service you have to register the service and have Windows start the service (via GUI or command line). When you register the service make sure that you are pointing to the debug build.

Then, in Visual Studio, attach to the running process, set a breakpoint in OnStop and then, use the GUI or command line to stop the service.